"I asked the waiter why there wasn't anyone else." VS "I asked the waiter why there was no one else."
I was speaking to a famous AI (chatgpt) today, and asked it to tell me if I made a mistake during speaking. And I was telling it about a new cafe I went to today. At one point, I said:

..... then I asked the waiter why there wasn't anyone else ...

And Chatgpt said "There wasn't anyone else" was a bit awkward, and changed it to "there was no one else," saying it sounded more natural.
I have always felt sure "... wasn't anyone else" and "... was no one else" are both OK, but I am not so sure now, as it has confused my mind. Do you think "There wasn't anyone else" doesn't sound natural?

anyone else is fine.But in your question you omitted two prepositions:speaking to, went to.    You could ask the waiter:  Why is the place so empty?

@TimR, Thanks I added the "to"s.

@MichaelHarvey Is it really important where the OP got their confusion from? The question would be the same if a friend had given them this advice.

And given the way that generative AI works, it probably drew this conclusion from finding more examples of one phrase than the other. Google Ngrams agrees.

Come on now: I saw no one. = semantically, I didn't see anyone. I left no package for you.= I didn't leave any package for you. First year English.
